Gibberish detector bot
Based on this question,- Why do we move? [closed], which shows that some questions can be so poorly formatted that they will have almost $99\%$ chances to be closed as off-topic for many reasons. Analyzing such questions for Physics SE community is a completely redundant/irrelevant when time spent doing it would be better used for writing answers to more qualified questions. Hence for respect of community time and intellectual resources, here comes the question,- Can Physics SE integrate another level of bot which automatically detects such "mild gibberish" and marks such questions as closed automatically ?
As for the prototype testing, for example you can run on the mentioned post this detector :
from transformers import pipeline
text = "POST text"
selected_model = "madhurjindal/autonlp-Gibberish-Detector-492513457"
classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model=selected_model)
c = classifier(text)
print(c)

When run on the mentioned post data,- this detector outputs :

{'label': 'mild gibberish', 'score': 0.8}

Despite the fact that there will be false positives and false negatives,- I think such Physics SE feature would be highly useful, since community could move-on to more targeted questions.
Is there any chances for gibberish detector implementation in SE Physics site ?
Thanks.

Where should this output go? There is a community of chat bots at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54445/sebotics which do many similar things; it would not be too hard to kick up a bot which runs your model and posts results there. The somewhat more vibrant parent project SOBotics is for Stack Overflow, but the same technologies work on Stack Exhange.

Don't know, I'm just posting raw prototype idea of additional question validation. In my current code snippet output is just printed to console. How this should be implemented in SE network and how output must be formatted and directed to - it's out of scope of this question.

Questions about the SE software may be more suited for Meta.SE. The only current automated mechanism I'm aware of is Charcoal which only handles spam and not bad questions. It uses user accounts to do its job. Perhaps something similar could work using close votes.

The thing is that some "bad questions" can be generated by online gibberish generators (which can generate Physics gibberish as well !) and can be actually a spam. So as for me, I see it as some sort of spam detection extension.

I think the linked question would be entirely comprehensible if the first run-on sentence were split into about six short sentences. I am skeptical of tools which purport to detect semantic gibberish — particularly as an intelligent human who currently understands ideas and texts that were once baffling.

@rob Are you sure that everybody reading such post will split original sentence in the same way for keeping same semantic meaning ? If not,- then which editor "splitting" is the correct interpretation of post ? The point is that what you try to do is try to think for original poster, which is basically impossible, because you is NOT him/her and while doing that you will mess post even worse, since while fixing it's semantics you will probably shift from whatever semantics OP had in mind. Some things are better left to the author for re-doing it's work and my bot proposal enforces that.

@AgniusVasiliauskas SE has a specific definition of spam: unsolicited material/advertisements posted for commercial gain and/or to drive traffic to an off-network website. Therefore, according to them, bad questions are not spam. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035 for details.

I'm never sure that well-punctated text will be understood as intended. I have written elsewhere about the value of tolerating "poor" English.

Vote to close as unclear if you think the post is unclear. Whether it's gibberish or not... personally, it's not that gibberish, only badly formatted. Here's Google Gemini attempting to fix it.

@VincentThacker At the peril of repeating myself, there are many quality-assurance bots in SOBotics, such as one which identifies possible duplicates, and one which detects possible plagiarism, and one which identifies posts in languages other than English. I encourage you to familiarise yourself with the SOBotics and SEBotics communities. There are simple libraries for multiple languages to interface with the Stack Exchange API and (separately) SO/SE chat. Since the OP is apparently asking about Python, I'll note that it's well supported. The Charcoal bot SmokeDetector is written in Python.
